# Magento2 render custom block in adminhtml layout.xml

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, blocks, template

I can not render **my custom block** within **my custom template**,

Point is on newsletter subscriber, I extend **`newsletter_subscriber_form.xml`**,

Add container within my block but it says that template is invalid,

When is added in existing reference block nothing happened,

When I put a template in an existing block of this layout

> (e.q. Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction)
>   It renders but I need my custom functionality.

**Layout block**

```
 <container name="content">
            <block class="Pool\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Button" name="button" template="Pool_Module:button.phtml" />
 </container>
```

**path of template is on Pool/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/button.phtml**

**Block**

```
<?php
namespace Pool\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Button extends Template
{
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function addNewSubscriber()
    {
        var_dump('hi');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to use below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Pool\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Button" name="button" template="Pool_Module:button.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file.

NOTE: <container name="content"> is added by me, he is not existing in certain layout.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your layout XML file (newsletter_subscriber_form.xml) to include your custom block correctly:

   ```
   <container name="content">
        <block class="Pool\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Button" name="button" template="Pool_Module::button.phtml" />
   </container>
   ```

   Make sure that your XML file is located in the correct directory: view/adminhtml/layout/newsletter_subscriber_form.xml.
2. Update your block class to extend \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template and implement the getAddNewSubscriberUrl method:

   ```
   <?php

      namespace Pool\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber;

      use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

      class Button extends Template
      {
         /**
          * Get URL for adding a new subscriber
          *
          * @return string
          */
        public function getAddNewSubscriberUrl()
        {
           return $this->getUrl('pool_module/subscriber/add');
        }
      }
   ```
3. Create the button.phtml template file in the correct directory:
   view/adminhtml/templates/button.phtml

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddNewSubscriberUrl()) ?>';">
   ```

In this example, I've used a button that redirects to a custom URL (pool_module/subscriber/add). You should replace it with the URL you want to use.